# Is there an easier way launch from my project from laragon local host to some public host?

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

When I was installing larval I was finding it extremely difficult to install it normally,so I installed it using laragon and wanted to know if I can easily import this to some public host?

Thanks and please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Valet. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet#sharing-sites):

> To share a site, navigate to the site's directory in your terminal and run the `valet share` command. A publicly accessible URL will be inserted into your clipboard and is ready to paste directly into your browser.